# python: loop through txt files and delete first few rows of strings

Tags: python, numpy, text, valueerror

I have text files where each file has 90 columns of timeseries data that vary in length. Before these 90 columns, there are 6 rows of junk string data I want to delete. From row 7 onward, the data is all of the type float.

I have tried the following but it made no change to my files:

```
folder = '/Users/LR/Desktop/S2'
files = os.listdir(folder)
for filename in files:
       lines = open(filename).readlines()
       open(filename, 'w').writelines(lines[6:])
```

I also tried loading the files and skipping over the first 6 rows, but numpy.loadtxt doesn't work unless I set the dtype = 'str'. It successfully cuts out the first 6 rows..  but it imports as a string ndarray object and I can't figure out how to convert it to a float array.

```
data = np.loadtxt('STS2.txt', delimiter = '\t', skiprows=6, dtype='str')
data = data.astype(float) # this gives the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

When I set the dtype = float, I get the same ValueError:

```
data_float = np.loadtxt('STS2.txt', delimiter='\t', dtype=float, skiprows=7) # this gives the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Anyone know a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably want to use `os.path.join(folder, filename)`.

Comment: Where would I add this to my code? Sorry, im new to python and coding in general

Comment: `open(os.path.join(folder, filename))` and `open(os.path.join(folder, filename), 'w')`

Comment: This worked for deleting the first 6 rows, thank you! But when I try and read the text files in, I still get the same Value Error: could not convert string to float, even though the data is just numbers

Comment: I think you'll have to share at least some of the contents of the file for anyone to help with that.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you're making the same mistake when reading the file (not specifying the correct full path)?

Comment: I tried the full path but still got the same value error. I edited my post to include sample text files. Some might contain more than 90 columns but we're only interested in the first 90 columns

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you sure that you're allowed to share that data just like that?

Comment: Yeah, its de-identified/anonymous data. If you mean sharing as a link to google drive.. im just not sure of a better way to share the files. Advice would be much appreciated

Comment: There's an extra field at the end of each row, so `numpy` is trying to parse an empty string as a `float` and failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last field of each row is an empty string, so `numpy` is unable to parse it as a `float`. You're only interested in the first 90 columns anyway, so add `usecols=range(90)`:

```
np.loadtxt('STS2.txt', skiprows=6, usecols=range(90))
```

(Of course, if you've already chopped off those first six rows, you can now drop the `skiprows=6`.)

**EDIT**

Since the first column just seems to be an index, you could use `usecols=range(1, 90)` to ignore it.

Comment: Perfect. thank you. How would I then overwrite the old txt files with the cleaned up ones?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. What cleaned up files?

Comment: @thymeandspace I guess you want [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)?

Comment: How would I save the new numpy arrays that do not contain the 6 junk rows at the top, or the extra columns so that they overwrite the old files?

Comment: I edited my post to show where my issue is. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas` to help you. Using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('STS1.txt', delimiter='\t', skiprows=[0,1,2], index_col=0)
df = df.T.set_index(np.nan, append=True).T
```

I was able to load the following table:

[image]

Note that your columns are now hierarchical. You can check your types:

```
df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
1      float64
2      float64
3      float64
4      float64
...
```

You can also convert the data easily e.g. to `int`:

```
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```